# Using Xpath and HtmlAgilityPack to find all elements with innertext containing a specific word or words

Tags: xpath, html-agility-pack

I am trying to build a simple search-engine using HtmlAgilityPack and Xpath with C# (.NET 4).
I want to find every node containing a userdefined searchword, but I can't seem to get the XPath right. 
For Example:

```
<HTML>
 <BODY>
  <H1>Mr T for president</H1>
   <div>We believe the new president should be</div>
   <div>the awsome Mr T</div>
   <div>
    <H2>Mr T replies:</H2>
     <p>I pity the fool who doesn't vote</p>
     <p>for Mr T</p>
   </div>
  </BODY>
</HTML>
```

If the specified searchword is "Mr T" I'd want the following nodes: `<H1>`, The second `<div>`, `<H2>` and the second `<p>`.
I have tried numerous variants of `doc.DocumentNode.SelectNodes("//text()[contains(., "+ searchword +")]");` but I always seem to wind up with every single node in the entire DOM.

Any hints to get me in the right direction would be very appreciated.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

**Use**:

```
//*[text()[contains(., 'Mr T')]]
```

This selects all elements in the XML document that have a text-node child which contains the string `'Mr T'`.

**This can also be written shorter as**:

```
//text()[contains(., 'Mr T')]/..
```

This selects the parent(s) of any text node that contains the string `'Mr T'`.

Comment: Your second expression matches exactly what the OP says he tried (except for the additional `..`), so I'm not sure why he thinks it didn't work.

Comment: @lwburk: It "didn't work, because it selects *text nodes* and he needs their parents.

Comment: Right, I get that, but it certainly doesn't select *"every single node in the entire DOM"* (as claimed).

Comment: OK, it turned out that I didn't do my homework properly... it wasn't the query itself that was the problem, but the way I coded the query! When I wrote ..."+ searchword +"... I actually got every node in the DOM... but when I tried ...'"+ searchword +"'... I got it right. But I wouldn't have got it if it wasn't for you guys! I actually tried my mock xml and got it right when I hardcoded the question just like Dimitres example, but when I did the same thing with the stringbased searchword, everythin else the same, I got all of the nodes again... Thank you very much!

Comment: That sure is some wonky expression there, but copy-paste replace 'Mr T' with 'My text' and it did exactly what i needed!

Answer (score 2):

According to Xpath, if you want to find a specific keyword you need to follow the format ("keyword" is the word you like to search) :

> //*[text()[contains(., 'keyword')]]

You have to follow the same format as above in C#, `keyword` is the string variable you call:

```
doc.DocumentNode.SelectNodes("//*[text()[contains(., '" + keyword + "')]]");
```

Comment: Please try explaining your answer with more detail. This will not only help the OP, but anyone else in the future that may have the same problem.

Comment: It's sensitive to small or capital alphabets. How can one ignore case sensitivity?

Answer (score 0):

Use the following:

```
doc.DocumentNode.SelectNodes("//*[contains(text()[1], " + searchword + ")]")
```

This selects all elements (`*`) whose first text child (`text()[1]`) contains the `searchword`.

Answer (score 0):

Case-insensitive solution:

var xpathForFindText = 
"//*[text()[contains(translate(., 'ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ', 'abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz'), '" + lowerFocusKwd + "')]]";

var result=doc.DocumentNode.SelectNodes(xpathForFindText);

Note:

Be careful, because the lowerFocusKwd must not contain the following character, because the xpath will be in bad format:

'